# Reduce Kafka Stream State Store Message size

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, windowing

I have kafka streams app that uses session windowing, during the specified window the number of messages for a given key can grow more than 30 MBs which exceeds the max.request.size when writing to state store topics. 
 
Is there a way to impose a limit on the size of the session window either in terms of size(MBs) or count(number of messages)?
I am looking to leverage some of the features of the Kstream instead of implementing this from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you care more about the number of messages than the time window you can use sliding windows, which will keep the last n records in a window. Also you can update the window.size.ms in the config or max.request.size in the producer config as well though you might need to tune some timeouts and other configs as well if you do that.

EDIT: it seems that this is a known problem is being worked on
[KIP_659](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-659%3A+Improve+TimeWindowedDeserializer+and+TimeWindowedSerde+to+handle+window+size)